# avoid deleting object, buttons and vba removing

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I do not know if it is a bug or not but each time I try to load a XLS template file with objects inside (ie buttons with linked vba)

Phpspreadsheet removes everything and I do not know how to avoid it.

```
    $reader = IOFactory::createReader('Xls');
    $reader->setReadDataOnly(false);
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load(Storage::disk('template')->path('template.xls'));

    $writer = new XlsWriter($spreadsheet);
    $writer->save(Storage::disk('template')->path('_test.xls'));
```

I also tried with $reader->setReadDataOnly(false); but it keeps failing.

For the moment I only try to open a template, named "template.xls" and write it to "_test.xls"

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPSpreadsheet don't support objects, buttons and vba. If you generate some new file all not supported thinks will delete from the excel.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will try something else then